# Injecting multiple property values to multiple beans

Tags: spring

I have handler bean with a url property which needs different value for different class injections .How can I do this without creating multiple beans

```
<bean id="handler" class="com.Handler">
<property name="url" value="/"/>
</bean>

<bean id="a" class="com.A">
<property name="handler" ref="handler">  for this I need url to be /aaa
</bean>

<bean id="b" class="com.B">
<property name="handler" ref="handler">  for this I need url to be /bbb
</bean>
```

.....

I do not want to create multiple handler beans

Comment: Define the property on beans a and b, and pass it as argument to the methods of the handler bean?